# derived class selection based on string - C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, crtp

Let's say I have classes `Square` and `Circle`, both derived from `Shape`, and a `Shape * p2shape` pointer, which should get a new object with type decided by `string shapeName`.

Currently, I am using the following approach:

```
enum class Shapes {square, circle};
std::map<string, Shapes> sMap;
sMap["square"] = Shapes::square;
sMap["circle"] = Shapes::circle;

switch (sMap[shapeName]) {
    case Shapes::square:
        p2shape = new Square();
        break;
    case Shapes::circle:
        p2shape = new Circle();
        break;
}
```

The downside of this is that adding a new derived class requires changes in three extra places:

- add new item to Class
- add the class to the map
- add the class to the `switch`

I decided to find an easier solution and ended up with two versions, both of which avoid the `switch`command by using pointers to static functions that create the new object:

```
class Square : public Shape {
public:
    static Shape * create() { return new Square(); }
};
class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    static Shape * create() { return new Circle(); }
};

std::map<string, Shape * (*) ()> sMap;
sMap["square"] = Square::create;
sMap["circle"] = Circle::create;

p2shape = sMap[shapeName]();
```

This means that a new derived class needs changes in only one extra place, the map. In addition, the each derived class has to have the static `create()` method. After some extra searching, I found that I can get rid of the latter requirement using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), at the cost of extra complexity:

```
template <class DerShapeT>
class Shape_CRTP : public Shape {
public:
    static Shape * create() { return new DerShapeT(); }
};
class Square : public Shape_CRTP<Square> {};
class Circle : public Shape_CRTP<Circle> {};

std::map<string, Shape * (*) ()> sMap;
sMap["square"] = Square::create;
sMap["circle"] = Circle::create;

p2shape = sMap[shapeName]();
```

Since I have never used (or even heard of) CRTP, I would like to ask whether there is some downside to this approach? (The upside being not requiring `create()` methods in all derived classes.)

And, even more to the point, is there some even better approach that I have not thought of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete [@Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24120006/2684539), you may use in C++11:

```
std::map<string, std::function<Shape*()>> sMap;
sMap["square"] = [](){ return new Square; };
sMap["circle"] = [](){ return new Circle; };

p2shape = sMap[shapeName]();
```

But even better to use smart pointer:

```
std::map<string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Shape>()>> sMap;
sMap["square"] = []() -> std::unique_ptr<Shape> { return std::make_unique<Square>(); };
sMap["circle"] = []() -> std::unique_ptr<Shape> { return std::make_unique<Circle>(); };

p2shape = sMap[shapeName]();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Shape_CRTP` template essentially a *factory* of shapes, so I'd name it `ShapeFactory`. And there's no need for it to inherit from `Shape` itself; you can decouple the factory from the shapes. And then you'll notice that the factory is just a wrapper for a single function without any state, so we can use a function template instead.

```
typedef Shape* (*ShapeFactory)();
template<class ShapeT>
Shape *newShape() {
  return new ShapeT();
}

class Square : public Shape {};
class Circle : public Shape {};

std::map<string, ShapeFactory> sMap;
sMap["square"] = &newShape<Square>;
sMap["circle"] = &newShape<Circle>;

p2shape = sMap[shapeName]();
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you can sidestep `ShapeFactory` entirely and somehow obtain a pointer to something like `operator new Square()`.

Comment: With C++11 lambda: `sMap["square"] = [](){ return static_cast<Shape*>(new Square); };`

Comment: @Thomas It's sometimes useful for the factory to be a class.  A class can have data, which could be passed to the constructor.  And a static object of class type has a constructor, which can take care of the insertion in the map.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. This is definitely the easiest solution - and it shows me I should really have a look at lambda functions :-)
If you write it as an answer, I will accept it; otherwise, I will accept Thomas'...

Comment: @Jarod42 BTW, this solution comes in its simplicity closest to my first idea about what would be nice to have, but (I believe) impossible in C++: a map from string to 'shape type', so I could write something like `p2shape = new sMap[shapeName]();`

Answer (score 1):

One common technique is to have an abstract base class builder, and to make the map a singleton.  The constructor of the base builder takes a string, and inserts a pointer to itself with the string as key into the map.  Each of the derived classes also creates a derived builder (generally private), whose constructor passes its type name to the base builder, and whose `build` function returns an instance of the correct type. The actual class also defines a static instance of this derived builder.

This has the advantage that you can add a derived class at any time, without modifying any common code.  In fact, you can put each derived class in a separate DLL, loaded explicitly at runtime, and recognize and build derived classes that didn't even exist when the base class and common code where compiled.  Or choose which DLLs to load, and thus which classes to support, from a configuration file.

The disadvantage is that it is a bit more typing.  This can partially be offset by making the concrete builders a template class, and more so by using macros (supposing they don't scare you too much).  But it is more complicated than some of the other solutions, and so should really only be used when the added flexibility is useful.

EDIT:

One more point: when inserting the factory into the map, you should use `insert`, and not the `[]` operator on map.  You want to test whether the insertion succeeded; it will fail if there is already an entry with the same name (where as `[]` will simply overwrite it).

EDIT:

As an example of how this might look:

```
class Shape
{
private:
    class AbstractBuilder;
    typedef std::map<std::string, AbstractBuilder const*> BuilderMap;
    static BuilderMap ourBuidlerMap;

protected:
    class AbstractBuilder
    {
    protected:
        ~AbstractBuilder() = default;
        AbstractBuilder( std::string const& typeName )
        {
            if ( !Shape::ourBuilderMap.insert( std::make_pair( typeName, this ) ).second ) {
                //  Some sort of fatal error...  or an exception
            }
        }
    public:
        virtual Shape* build() const = 0;
    };

public:
    static Shape* build( std::string const& typeName )
    {
        BuilderMap::const_iterator builder = ourBuilderMap.find( typeName );
        return builder == ourBuilderMap.end()
            ? nullptr
            : builder->build();
    }
};
```

and in each derived class:

```
class Square : public Shape
{
private:
    class Builder : public Shape::AbstractBuilder
    {
    public:
        Builder() : Shape::AbstractBuilder( "square" ) {}
        Shape* build() const { return new Square; }
    }
    static Builder ourBuilder;
//  ...
};
```

Of course, you'll have to provide an actual instance for each of
the static objects.  And you may or may not want the builders,
etc. to be nested.  There are lots of variants: you can create
a template for the derived builders in the Shape class, and then
just write:

```
static Shape::ConcreteBuilder<Square> ourBuilder;
```

and pass the name of the type in the definition of the static
variable, for example.  Or if you have several keywords which
resolve to the same class, but with different initializers, you
can create a single builder for it, with the keyword and the
initializer as arguments, and the `new` in the `build` function
would use member variables initialized with the constructor
arguments.

Comment: This is unnecessarily complex for my use, but an interesting approach nevertheless. Could you sketch the code, or provide a link to some example (since you call it a common technique)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map of class specific factory functions instead of a map of class identifier values.

You can encapsulate that in a general factory function.

The sketched solution attempt using CRTP is in that direction, but the CRTP aspect is wholly irrelevant, a not needed complication.